# 間違えて作成したアカウントを統合・マージ・リンクする方法はありますか？

Tags: サポート, よくある質問

- 既にアカウントを持っていることを忘れて、もう一つ作ってしまった
- ユーザー登録せずに質問したあとで、新たにユーザー登録してしまった

上記のような理由でアカウントを複数作成してしまい、自分の投稿にコメントをつけたり、回答に承認マークを付けることができません。どうしたらいいですか？

[←FAQ目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

問い合わせフォームから、アカウントのマージを依頼することができます。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact

まずマージしたい2つのアカウントのうち、どちらかでログインした状態で上記URLにアクセスして、「ユーザープロフィールをマージする必要があります」を選択します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

「メールアドレス」「プロフィールリンク」には現在ログインしているアカウントの情報が表示されているので、「その他のプロフィールリンク」にもう一方のアカウントのプロフィールURLを記入します。質問や回答の右下にアイコンとユーザー名が表示されていますが、このリンク先がプロフィールページです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### Q. マージ処理は自動で行われますか？

両方のアカウントの信用度が低ければ、自動処理が行われます。具体的には、両方のアカウントのメールアドレスに確認リンクが送信され、両方ともクリックされるとマージが行われます。

それ以外の場合はStackExchange社のコミュニティチームによって確認されます。

参考 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250982/286934

### Q. 2つのアカウントのうち、どちらが残りますか？

古い（IDが小さい）アカウントに対して、新しいアカウントがマージされます。

プロフィールの内容はどちらか一方のみが残ることになりますが、これまでに投稿した質問・回答・コメントや、ログインに使っているIDなどは統合されるため、失われることはありません。

参考 [Which profile details does an account merge preserve?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267262/286934)